# Динамические одномерные массивы через указатели, их сортировка и сравнивание

Tags: массивы, сортировка, указатели

Дано натуральное число `N` и два одномерных массива: `A1, A2, …, AN` и `B1, B2, …, BN`, целых чисел.

Определить, правильно ли, что эти два массива различаются расположением элементов.

Comment: `a.sort()`, `b.sort()`, поэлементно сравнить

Answer (score 1):

1. `a.sort()`,
2. `b.sort()`,
3. поэлементно сравнить